# How to reload dashlet in Alfresco Share using Ajax or simple javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, alfresco-share

I have a hyperlinks in dashlet A in Alfresco Share as menu items. Dashlet B is also in Alfresco Share. What I'm trying to do is, when I click on one of the hyperlinks in dashlet A, code should do the following:
(i)pass a parameter to dashlet B
(ii)based on the parameter passed, load the html (innerhtml) to the dashlet B ftl
(iii)this should be the case for all the hyperlinks in dashlet A.

It will be very helpful. Thank you.